# Iron python: How to append string to bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, ironpython

I have a `bytearray` to which I have to add a number as a four character string. i.g. 14 should be added as '0014'.

I tried this:

```
id = 14
arr.append(bytearray(format(id, '04x')))
```

but it results in:
`TypeError: unicode argument without an encoding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you should explicitly specify the encoding when converting to bytes from a string. This answer also works in python 3:

```
arr.extend(format(id, "04x").encode('ascii'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.extend(bytes(format(id,"04x")))
```

Comment: This errors in python 3 with `TypeError: string argument without an encoding`