# Append string to bytearray

Tags: python, python-bytearray

I have a byte array, `arr` and a hexadecimal number `a`:

```
arr = bytearray()
a = 'FE'
```

How can I append this number to bytearray to have the same value, `FE`? I tried with `print(int(a, 16))`, but it seems to be a bad idea (it prints `254` instead of `FE`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iron python: How to append string to bytearray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656250/iron-python-how-to-append-string-to-bytearray)

Comment: Everything is correct - you parse the hex value using `int` into an integer and then `print` outputs the decimal representation. `FE` in hex is `254` in dec. Just use `arr.append(int(a, 16))` and everything will be correct. Or you want to append it as a string, like two characters?

Comment: @Eswcvlad: If `FE` is `254` that's fine. I forgot to recalculate this. So it seems ok now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 254 is correct because 'FE' is hexadecimal for 254: `F = 15`, `E = 14`: `15 * 16**1 + 14 * 16**0 = 254`

But if you want to append the characters you could use `extend`:

```
>>> arr = bytearray()
>>> arr.extend('FE'.encode('latin-1'))  # you can also choose a different encoding...
>>> arr
bytearray(b'FE')
```

Comment: How about use `ba = bytearray(b"FE")`?

Comment: @stamaimer Not sure what you mean, I thought the variable `'FE'` was given as variable (string), so you would need to convert it anyway (`encode`).